# Split String (Hexadecimal) into two letter blocks

Tags: split, sql-server-2008-r2

MSSQL 2008r2

I want to split a string (Hexidecimal) into two letter (for want of a better term - 2 byte?) blocks.  The string will always be an even number in length.

For example

Split `'1424EBC312'`

into

```
12
C3
EB
24
14
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similar problem, here's what I did.

I used a Numbers table for this solution.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1424EBC312'     
SELECT 
     SUBSTRING( @string, N.N , 2 )
    ,@string
FROM
    dbo.Numbers N
WHERE
    N.N <= LEN(@string)
AND
    N.N % 2 = 1
```